# Why does my wireless router reset when I connect with my laptop?

Tags: wireless-networking

Whenever I connect to my wireless network at home through my laptop, the connection always resets every 5 mins, and the modem restarts automatically.

This only happens when I connect my laptop, as my other roommate's laptop connects fine to the network.

Comment: Also, what operating system are you using? (and what version of the OS?)

Comment: We need specific hardware information to help further. Make/model of router, make/model of laptop wireless adapter. If wireless is internal, make/model of laptop.

Comment: How did you determine that the modem restarts? By watching the lights on it?

Answer (score 0):

Are your 802.11 access point and your broadband modem the same box? If so, then it sounds like you found a bug that's crashing that box. Either get a better modem/wireless router, or get a different brand of wireless card that hopefully won't trigger the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the driver to your WiFi card, if one is available.

If problem persists, find if a firmware upgrade is available for the router. In this case, take precautions to be able to force a return to the current firmware version, in case you brick the router.

If problem still persists, find a better router.